# Strange behavior with execution permission

Tags: permissions, bash, executable

For exercise -  I removed execute permission for others from /bin/pwd:

```
$ chmod o-x /bin/pwd
$ ls -l /bin/pwd
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 26568 Apr 28  2010 /bin/pwd
```

and as logged as matt I cannot execute /bin/pwd as expected:

```
$ /bin/pwd
$ -bash: /bin/pwd: Permission denied
```

but sudden it can be executed if not absolute:

```
$ pwd
/home/matt
```

Why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pwd` is a shell built-in. You can see that with

```
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
```

`pwd` is a built-in in most shells. One reason for that is that it's a very simple command that's used fairly frequently (and running a built-in is faster than spawning an external process). Another reason is that it allows the shell to track symbolic links, so that `cd /foo/bar; pwd` shows `/foo/bar` even if `bar` is a symbolic to `/wibble` (in bash and many other shells, you can use `pwd -P` to show `/foo/bar` and `pwd -L` to show `/wibble`; the default is controlled by the `-o physical` option).

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't know that pwd is a built-in! Wow!